# SessionManager повторное подключение

Tags: java, android, media

При выходе из сна на ммс теряется подключение к mediaController. После выхода из сна я повторно использую код для подключения:

```
mediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
         getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "." + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    try {
         mediaSessionManager.addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener(sessionListener, componentName);
         List<MediaController> controllers = mediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions(componentName);
         mediaController = pickController(controllers);
         if (mediaController != null) {
             mediaController.registerCallback(callback);
             meta = mediaController.getMetadata();
             updateMetadata();
         }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
}
```

Подключение почему-то происходит не с первого раза. И поэтому, если у меня нет играющей музыки, то я в логах получаю сообщение

```
W/SessionManager: Attempted to add session listener twice, ignoring
```

Понятно что я повторно добавляю мультимедиа сессию, но нигде не могу найти код для проверки, подключена ли медиасессия. Если кто знает, подскажите как избежать этого предупреждения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение

```
if (mediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions(componentName) == null) {
    mediaSessionManager.addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener(sessionListener, componentName);
}
```